React native NumericInput WARN "md-add" is not a valid icon name for family "ionicons"
can anyone help - I've recently upgraded my expo react native app to expo 50.0.0. The plus and minus icons on NumericInput are now showing as question marks and i get the above warning for md-remove and md-add. I needed to go to expo 50.0.0 to stop Drawr menu sticking so I don't want to regress it. It's driving me a bit nuts and I can't find that error anywhere else on any searches. Thanks!! I'm running in ios and android emulators and same errors, and same error in preview builds for device.
Here is where I import it;
import NumericInput from "react-native-numeric-input";

Here is my use;
  <NumericInput
      initValue={playerHcp}
      value={playerHcp}
      onChange={(hcp) => playerHcpHandler({ hcp })}
      totalWidth={70}
      totalHeight={sizes.newGameInputHeight}
      fontSize={sizes.newGameFontSize}
      minValue={0}
      maxValue={54}
      textColor="#59656F"
      borderColor="#C7CBD6"
      iconStyle={{ color: "white" }}
      rightButtonBackgroundColor="#009900"
      leftButtonBackgroundColor="#06BA63"
    />

...and here is my package.json;
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/helper-get-function-arity": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@expo-google-fonts/kanit": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^7.8.0",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "^6.7.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.1.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.2.10",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.3.9",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^7.0.5",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1593.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "expo": "^50.0.0",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.7.0",
    "expo-clipboard": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.6",
    "expo-dev-client": "~3.3.11",
    "expo-file-system": "~16.0.9",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.3",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.8.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.7.1",
    "expo-in-app-purchases": "^14.5.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-vector-icons": "^10.0.1",
    "graphql": "15.8.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-art": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.2.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.2",
    "react-native-modal-overlay": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.9.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.2.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.4",
    "react-native-purchases": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-radio-buttons-group": "^2.2.11",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-simple-dropdown": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "rn-country-picker": "^1.0.1",
    "util": "^0.12.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "bu-app",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}

Has anyone else seen this or got any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the packages connected with vector icons, fonts etc

Did you fin a workaround?

I find a workaround which is to change a little bit the "react-native-numeric-input" package in your node_modules (NumericInput.js) and patch it with "patch-package" here : https://github.com/ds300/patch-package.
So first :
npm i patch-package
or
npx expo install patch-package

In your package.json, add :
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "patch-package",

Then in your node_modules go to node_modules/react-native-numeric-input/NumericInput/NumericInput.js.
Change this line :
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

For this line or another Icon Families that you can find here (I chose AntDesign) : https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign'

Then, in the same file, change the two icons that cause issues, search for: 'md-add' and 'md-remove' and change it for whatever you chose, for me 'plus' and 'minus'.
<Icon name='md-add' size={fontSize} style={[...iconStyle, maxReached ? this.props.reachMaxIncIconStyle : {}, minReached ? this.props.reachMinIncIconStyle : {}]} />

After that you have to patch everything to don't lose your changes when you will npm install another time :
npx patch-package react-native-numeric-input

That's it.
Sorry for my english, if someone would like to correct it. Thanks.
